# Asp.Net Core and Application Insight in VS2017 - multiple environments

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Prior VS2017, it was possible to setup Application Insight integration into an Asp.NET Core application in the code. In VS2017, it is only possible using the IDE(Connected Services) as the "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore"(2.0.0.) does not offer `builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);` extension anymore. All the related resources does not work for VS2017(ie https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started).

When using new VS2017 feature "Connected Services", how we are supposed to connect to different Application Insights instances per environment?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is still possible to set ApplicationInsights manually using `ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions`. Here is the source code, how the settings are actually resolved:

```
internal static void AddTelemetryConfiguration(IConfiguration config, ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions serviceOptions)
{
  string str1 = config["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1))
    str1 = config["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1))
    serviceOptions.InstrumentationKey = str1;
  string str2 = config["APPINSIGHTS_DEVELOPER_MODE"];
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2))
    str2 = config["ApplicationInsights:TelemetryChannel:DeveloperMode"];
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2))
  {
    bool result = false;
    if (bool.TryParse(str2, out result))
      serviceOptions.DeveloperMode = new bool?(result);
  }
  string str3 = config["APPINSIGHTS_ENDPOINTADDRESS"];
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str3))
    str3 = config["ApplicationInsights:TelemetryChannel:EndpointAddress"];
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str3))
    serviceOptions.EndpointAddress = str3;
  string str4 = config["version"];
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str4))
    return;
  serviceOptions.ApplicationVersion = str4;
}
```

So you can see the highest priority have the Environment Variables. You can set the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` variable in Azure Application settings and it will be picked up.

If the VS2017 Connected Services setup is used, it stores its configuration into `csproj`, `appsettings.json`(InstrumentationKey) and `/Connected Services/Application Insights/ConnectedServices.json`.

Comment: The method AddTelemetryConfiguration can be found in the class ApplicationInsightsExtensions.