# Application Insights ASP.NET Core Environment appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-service-fabric, appsettings

I am trying to configure Application Insights within a ASP.NET app running in Service Fabric.

It works well on my dev box when settings the following in the appsettings.json:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I also have a appsettings.Production.json file with the following settings:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

But for some reason, when I publish the app to a Production environment the app keeps posting to the Dev Application Insights Key xxxx-xxx-xxx...... Seems like the Production Application Insights Key is not used.

I have the following setting in the Startup.cs:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Also, the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable on my nodes are not set (which means it defaults to Production). To make sure, I am outputting the environment value to the View to make sure and it does render "Production"

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to follow this post: [Asp.Net Core and Application Insight in VS2017 - multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943182/asp-net-core-and-application-insight-in-vs2017-multiple-environments) but I couldn't understand it.

Hooroo

Comment: Take a look at this sample to use SF configuration for AI keys: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/dev/appinsights/ApplicationInsights.md

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj, thanks. By using this method, should I remove ApplicationInsight settings from the Startup.cs for my ASP.NET Web SF service?

Comment: no - it's just how you get the key from configuration to your code.

Comment: Mmmm ok. I followed the instructions in the link you provided but I also removed all my old AI settings from my Startup.cs and appsetting.json files and it all works fine. The code supplied in the constructor of my asp.net Stateless service seems to be enough.

Comment: Glad you got it to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#providers. Based on this article, `appsettings.json` supersedes the environment-specific `appsettings.<environment>.json` files. So in your case, just rename your *default* `appsettings.json` to `appsettings.development.json`.